# clicking button only once with method with parameters?

Tags: html, angularjs

guys ive googled so many events listeners and functions to let me use this button only once:

```
<button id="skillVillainB" class="ggV" *ngIf="chosenHero" (click)="skillUseHero(chosenVillain, chosenHero);onButtonClick1();">{{chosenHero.skill.name}}
      ({{chosenHero.skill.damage}})</button>
```

but it doesnt work since skillUseHero has parameters...

Comment: so what framework is this? Angular? You need to tag it more than just "html"

Comment: Your [Google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+click+only+once+site:stackoverflow.com) is lacking ;)

Comment: yes angular it is my frend

Comment: @mplungjan still cant find anything that actually works without giving me 1000 errors

Comment: [This should work just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384973/angular-ng-click-only-want-user-to-click-once-not-multiple-times-on-a-rating-s)

Comment: ng click and ng-disabled dont even exist in my project